# Solve $\sqrt{3}^n=3^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got answer but i could not understand, can anyone explain me ?

$\sqrt{3}^n=3^3$

$\implies{3}^{n/2}=3^3$

$\implies \frac{n}{2}=3\implies n=6$

How we get ${3}^{n/2}$ in the second line and how we get $\frac{n}{2}$ in third line.

Comment: $\sqrt{3} = 3^{1/2}$. Then take log base $3$ both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will make it easier for you to understand:

$(\sqrt3)^n=(3)^3\iff$

$(\sqrt3)^n=(\sqrt3^2)^3\iff$

$(\sqrt3)^n=(\sqrt3)^{2\cdot3}\iff$

$(\sqrt3)^n=(\sqrt3)^6\iff$

$n=6$

Comment: Going from $(3)^\frac{n}{2} = 3^3$ to $\frac{n}{2} = 3$ is ambiguous because the exponent and base on the RHS are the same. This clears that ambiguity, so +1.

Comment: @scott: Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$ {\sqrt{3}}^{n} = 3^3$

$\Rightarrow$ $({\sqrt{3}}) ^{n} = 3^3$

$\Rightarrow$ $({3}^{1/2}) ^{n} = 3^3$

$\Rightarrow$ $({3}) ^{{(1/2)}.{n}} = 3^3$

$\Rightarrow$ $({3}) ^{n/2} = 3^3$

$\Rightarrow$ $n/2 = 3$

$\Rightarrow$ $n = 6$

Comment: How did you wrote $({3}^{1/2}) ^{n}$

Comment: You can right-click on the expression and then click on "Show Math As" "TeX Commands". This will give you the equivalent TeX notation.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{3}\equiv3^{\frac{1}{2}}$

The radical--or square root sign--notation is equivalent to the fractional exponent notation. Since raising a rational power to another rational power is equivalent to multiplying the powers together:

$\left(3^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^n=3^{\frac{n}{2}}$

It appears that you understand how to solve the rest of the problem, or at least don't have any questions on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Taking logs,  $n.1/2$log$_{3}$ $3$ = $3$ log$_{3}$$3$

Now, log$_{3}$$3$ = $1$.

Hence we have $n/2$ = $3$ $=>$ $n=$6

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Since if $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x} = x$ by definition then it follows that $x^kx^k = x^1$ where $2k = 1$ so $k = \frac{1}{2}$. If you choose to agree with this, then

$$\sqrt{3^n} = \sqrt{3}^\frac{n}{2} = 3^3  \implies \frac{n}{2} = 3 \implies n = 6$$